# Submarine screw and the isolation from the water

Tags: motor, design

How does the submarine prevent water flow through the screw mechanism? The mechanism rotates the screw so there should be a little gap, how come the water doesn't come through this gap in to the submarine?

Comment: related: ["Preventing leaks in motor shafts for underwater bots"](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/150/preventing-leaks-in-motor-shafts-for-underwater-bots)

Comment: @DavidCary ty. the answer it contains is exactly what I was looking for.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variety of techniques are used for propeller shaft sealing.  One of the most common is a "packing gland" or "stuffing box", as in illustration below from a [dieselduck.info](http://www.dieselduck.info/machine/04%20auxiliary/stuffing_box.htm) web page which has details of using such seals.

[image: packing gland]

Also see [boatus.com](http://www.boatus.com/boattech/casey/stuffing-box.asp), which describes how much leakage to allow, and when to repack.  Two or three drops of leakage per minute is recommended; the leakage helps lubricate the shaft where it passes through the seal. Leakage gets pumped out of the vessel as necessary.
For some submarines, high leakage rates occur.  For example, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collins-class_submarine#Propulsion_system)  notes that

> Propeller shaft seals were a significant problem on Collins and Farncomb.  Although designed to allow for a leak of 10 litres per hour, during trials it was found that the seals would regularly misalign and allow hundreds of litres per hour into the boat – during one deep diving test the flow rate was measured at approximately 1,000 litres a minute.

Other kinds of propeller shaft seals (oil or grease filled, gas filled, with carbon plates, o-rings, etc) may leak less or not at all. ([1](http://www.shaftseal.com/en/categories), [2](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-do-you-seal-a-rotor-underwater.323819/)).